# Error while installing cocoa pods on macbook with Yosemite 10.10.5

Tags: macos, cocoapods

I am trying to install cocoa pods on macbook which is running Yosemite 10.10.5, and also this macbook is provided by my company so its having some security.
When I run "sudo gem install cocoapods" command in terminal, i am getting following

```
Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0), here is why:
      Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - no such name (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

I tried all the solution provide on almost every post but i didn't get the solution. Please help he on this.

Comment: looks like a communication error, are you able to install other gems?

Comment: @rmaddy can you please guild me to install other gems